# list-style-type with YUI reset.css?

Tags: css, yui, yui-reset

I am using yui reset:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.0r4/build/reset/reset-min.css"/>
```

and I'm having a hard time getting my ordered lists to show with `decimal`.

So far I'm using this, but it still seems to be overwritten to be blank?

```
ol, ol li{
    list-style-type: decimal;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can un-reset these styles. See: http://noscope.com/vanilla-css

What I prefer to do it have a wrapping class for my un-reset items. This way the reset remains universal everywhere else.

```
/* un-reset bullets */

.bullets ul {
    margin:0 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
}

.bullets ul li {
    list-style-type:disc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use specificity to override the reset styles by using a class or id in front of your selector.

Using your developer console in Chrome or FF should be really useful in figuring out how to overwrite or determine the cause.

If you could provide a URL I would be happy to take a look.

GL!